# Drawing in SVG layers using swift

Tags: ios, swift, svg, drawing, cashapelayer

[image]Hi I want to drawline within svg layer or you can say in cashapelayers of view code is work to draw line but it draw outside too any suggestion or help to avoid this thanks . 
here is my code,

kindly check attached image i want something like this.

```
 open override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first!
        currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        self.pointMoved = true
        let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1 / scaleForCTM, y: 1 / scaleForCTM)
        let scaledPoint = currentPoint.applying(scaleTransform)
        let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -translateForCTM.x, y: -translateForCTM.y)
        let translatedPoint = scaledPoint.applying(translateTransform)



        if let layer = self.drawingLayer?.hitTest(translatedPoint) as? CAShapeLayer {

         //   let point = CGPoint(x: translatedPoint.x, y: translatedPoint.y)
          //  setNeedsDisplay()
       //     drawLine(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint,layer: layer)
                // 7
            if let layer1 = layer.hitTest(translatedPoint) as? CAShapeLayer { // If you hit a layer and if its a Shapelayer


                let   currentPoint1 = (self.drawingLayer?.convert(translatedPoint, to: layer1))!
                if layer.path!.contains(currentPoint1) {
                 //   print ("We tapped the square")

            //    print(currentPoint1)
                //drawLine(from: lastPoint, to: currentPoint1, layer: layer1)

               // print("current--\(currentPoint1) --- prev--\(lastPoint)")
              drawLineFromPointToPoint(startX: Int((lastPoint.x)), toEndingX: Int((currentPoint1.x)), startingY: Int((currentPoint1.y)), toEndingY: Int((lastPoint.y)), ofColor: fillColor, widthOfLine: 10, inLayer:layer1)
                lastPoint = currentPoint1
                }
 }

          //  let point_layer = CALayer(layer: (self.layer.presentation()?.hitTest(translatedPoint)))

         //   drawLineFromPoint(start: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint, ofColor: fillColor, inLayer: layer)


            self.shapesLayers?.append(layer)
        }

        self.setNeedsDisplay()

        //self.strokePath()
    }
```

Comment: Did you get the solution ?

Comment: i did not get it kashif.

Comment: Did you get any solution @kashifasif ?